# Azure DevOps YAML "each" syntax

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I'm struggling with the syntax of the `each` keyword in YAML templates.

Essentially, I'm passing a list of jobs to a template. The template should execute those jobs, filtering out unwanted variable groups.

`template.yml:`

```yaml
parameters:
- name: DeployJobs
  type: jobList

jobs:
- ${{ each job in parameters.DeployJobs }}:
    ${{ if job.variables }}:
      variables:
      - ${{ each var in job.variables }}:
        - ${{ each pair in var }}:
            ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'var-group-blue') }}:
              - group: ${{ pair.value }}
```

`azure-pipelines.yml:`

```yaml
jobs:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    DeployJobs:
    - deployment: mydeployjob
      variables:
      - group: var-group-blue # the template should filter out this var group
      - group: var-group-green
...
```

But I'm getting the compilation errors `Expected a mapping` and `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the line:

`- group: ${{ pair.value }}`

Can anyone offer advice on what syntax or indenting that I may be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing a dash on the `if` clause. The specifics of when to use dashes and how much to indent are extremely arcane and poorly documented in the docs.

Working solution:

```yaml
# template.yml

parameters:
- name: DeployJobs
  type: jobList

jobs:
- ${{ each job in parameters.DeployJobs }}:
    ${{ if job.variables }}:
      variables:
      - ${{ each var in job.variables }}:
        - ${{ each pair in var }}:
          - ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'var-group-blue') }}:
            - group: ${{ pair.value }}
```

```yaml
# azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    DeployJobs:
    - deployment: mydeployjob
      variables:
      - group: var-group-blue # the template should filter out this var group
      - group: var-group-green
...
```

Comment: Why is that the first "if" does not need a dash and the second "if" does when both are under an each statement? It does not make any sense!

Comment: My observation regarding dashes is that you need a dash when you are replacing a line which would have a dash, first `if` is in a place of `variables:` therefore no dash, second `if` is in a place where `- group:` would be, hence a dash.